# Problems with form validation plugin HTML5FORM

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the form validation plugin HTML5FORM (http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/jquery-plugin-ajax-form-validation-html5.html) but i need to run something after the form is check and everything is Ok.

How should I proceed?

this is the script for validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_lista').html5form({
        responseDiv:'#response2',
        method: 'post',
        messages: 'br',
        colorOn:'#6b6764',
        colorOff:'#000000',
        allBrowsers:true
    });
});
```

my button is:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_third" value="" />
```

When the user click on Submit button i need to check if the user fill all fields of the form, if its ok, i need execute the script for update progress bar and slide steps:

```
$('#submit_third').click(function(){

//update progress bar
    $('#progress_text').html('100% Completo');
    $('#progress').css('width','339px');
    //slide steps
    $('#third_step').slideUp();
    $('#fourth_step').slideDown();
```

});

Comment: It doesn't look like that plugin has any hooks to call a function before submit, so you'd have to add one.

Comment: yeah... i need to use the Validation from jQuery... thanks for help